# How do I get a partial result from http response python while data is still coming?

Tags: python, python-2.7, http, urllib

I am making a request to a server but the HTML page is very long and it takes a long time to send the whole data. I want to start processing as soon some data arrives. Like the browsers which renders as soon as there are data from top to bottom. 
How can I do this in python? Can urllib be used for this purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

urllib itself is ill-equipped for this purpose. The [`urlretrieve()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) method allows for a callback. However, that is only for mere reporting, not actual data processing. [urllib2](/questions/tagged/urllib2) is offering no improvement in this regard.

However, the [requests lib](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) is quite promising in the [event hooks](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#event-hooks) offered.